# Why we should not do rs.next inside RowCallBackHandler?

Tags: spring, jdbctemplate

I am able to put `while(rs.next())` inside `RowCallBackHandler` where as per spring doc it is not supposed to be done. Why it is not supposed to be done? I can understand that this `while(rs.next())` can be done without a `RowCallBackHandler`. But why spring is allowing this inside the `RowCallBackHandler` if it not supposed to be done?

Comment: Because Spring is already calling `rs.next`. The name `RowCallbackHandler` implies that it is called for each row in the results set. If you want to do it yourself use a `ResultsetExtractor`. Spring simply calls `next()` and passes the `ResultSet` to the method.

Comment: I agree  but RowCallBackHandler is used for processing each row. for example creating an XML document. If that is the case, should the spring take care of not allowing doing rs.next inside processRow method?

Comment: No why should it. As that would mean adding an extra layer of indirection and performance. The JDBC material is a convenience wrapper around the plain JDBC classes.

Comment: Ok. When i use rs.next inside the RowCallBackHandler i see a performance number which is less than the performance number without the while(rs.next) for a large result set of greater than 300K records. In this case why i should go for RowCallBackHandler? For a better maintainability of the code? or it has any specific significance, may be i am not aware of that.

Comment: Easy of use. It lets you focus on  what is important not the nuts and bolts of retrieving the results. As stated if you want to do it yourself use a `ResultSetExtractor`. There is some overhead in using the `RowCallbackHandler` because an integer is calculated and it is an additional method call those things add to a little time to each record processing.

Comment: Since i need to process each row to convert into a different format, i am going with RowCallBackHandler. Thanks.